# обновление переменной каждые доли секунды

Tags: javascript

Возникла необходимость обновлять значение переменной каждую секунду. Как это сделать в javascript?

Конкретнее: есть переменная ss, которая хранит секунды. Как сделать так, чтобы ее значение обновлялось каждую секунду?

Comment: setTimeout? и записывать по колбеку

Answer (score 0):

Используйте сетинтервал

```
var ss = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    ss++;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: у этого кода есть куча проблем, не?

Comment: @KoVadim, например? :-)

Comment: "есть переменная ss ,которая хранит секунды". а у нас это просто счетчик. Да, он будет похож на секунды, но со временем такой счетчик будет отставать.

Comment: @KoVadim смотря какие секунды имеются в виду - точные текущие или например секунды в мире игры

Comment: я думаю, что автор все таки имеет ввиду секунду реального времени.

Comment: @KoVadim да, скорее всего так, но автор вопроса ничего не пояснил. Лучше может быть вообще их вычислять в дробном виде в каждом месте использования.

Comment: я бы запоминал время при первом обращении/инициализации, таймер завел на половину желаемого интервала (в данном случае это скорее всего пол секунды) и через `ss = (Date.now() - start ) / 1000;` обновлял

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```js
class timer {
  #start;
  constructor() {
    this.#start = new Date();
  }
  get time() {
    return ((new Date() - this.#start) / 1000) | 0;
  }
}

let t = new timer();
setTimeout(() => console.log(t.time), 2000)
setTimeout(() => console.log(t.time), 5000)
```

Comment: У Вас не выполняется главное требование - обновление каждую секунду.

Comment: А какой смысл обновлять, если обновленное значение не используется? Просто чтобы процессор не застаивался? А так при чтении всегда будет актуальное значение.

Comment: Все зависит от сценария использования. Если это значение требуется получать 100 раз в секунду - мой вариант, конечно, будет неэффективен. А вот если несколько раз в минуту - тогда совсем другое дело. :)